# Implementing UI

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've created a simple UI (a label and a button) in Xamarin.Forms using the default MainPage.xaml that is present upon creating a new project. I now want to add a button click event to that button, but I can't seem to figure out how. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I imagine the Xamarin site has pretty detailed documentation.  There are likely plenty of beginner's videos on YouTube as well.  I would look there for something you can follow along with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XAML add the Clicked property to your Button

```
<Button Text="Click!"
        Clicked="ButtonClicked" />
```

Next specify that delegate in your MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to the docs for more detail: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/getting_started_with_xaml/

Comment: Just a small one, but the naming convention for `On*` methods is that they are the methods that raise the events. It's usual that the handlers don't start with `On`.

Comment: Thanks! in my .cs there is already existing code, where exactly do put this code? There's public MainPage{} inside Partial Class MainPage : ContentPage{} inside Namespace App1{} EDIT: I just saw your link, I will read through that

Comment: You want to put it inside the class, as it's a method and it can't exist outside a class. So inside Partial Class MainPage : ContentPage {}.

public MainPage() {} is a constructor so you won't specify it inside there.

The namespace is basically used to organise/group classes

Comment: Thank you for all the help @TripWire